# How to check if two time values are in the same date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, sql-server-2012

How to check two times if they are in the same date or not ?

For example

```
first-    08:00:00
second-    16:00:00
```

> in the same date .

---

```
first-    20:00:00
 second-    04:00:00
```

> two different dates

Comment: how is first example in same date ?

Comment: `first-    20:00:00; second- 20:00:00` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.first > t.second THEN 'Two different dates'
            ELSE 'In the same date'
       END as your_ind
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that if the time of the first value is higher than the time of the second value it is a different date?

If so you can simply use  less than or greater than:

```
declare @t1 time = '08:00:00'
declare @t2 time = '16:00:00'
declare @t3 time = '20:00:00'
declare @t4 time = '04:00:00'

if (@t1 < @t2)
    PRINT 'same day'

if (@t3 > @t4 )
print 'different day'
```